# При обновлении ng-repeat срывается скролл соседнего элемента

Tags: angularjs, прокрутка, angular

Проблема проста. На странице имеется `ng-repeat` и в соседнем диве лежит `iframe` с подгруженной страницей. Когда в контроллер приходят новые данные и ng-repeat отображает их на странице, скролл соседнего фрейма чаще всего срывается и прыгает наверх.

Что тут можно придумать?

```
<html ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="mycontrol">
<div class="list-container">
   <div>
       <div ng-repeat="el in els track by $index">
           <div ng-bind-html-unsafe="html">{{el.title}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button>
            <span>Example</span>
        </button>
        <button>
            <span>Example</span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="frame-container">
    <iframe class="frame" sandbox="allow-same-origin"></iframe>
</div>
</html>
```

**css**

```
.list-container {
    display: inline-block;
}

.frame-container {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    border: none;
    overscroll-behavior-y: contain;
    overflow: scroll !important;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch !important;
}

.frame {
    border: none;
}
```

См. гифку. `ng-repeat` в колонке слева. Когда приходит элемент с именем slwiki, скролл срывается.

[image: см]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась. Этот баг не связан с AngularJS, а возникает исключительно в мобильных браузерах на iOS при повторном рендеринге и решается помещением в код отображаемой в `iframe` странице следующего стиля:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

Подробнее: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34766636/ios-browser-iframe-jumps-to-top-when-changing-css-or-content-using-javascript